# Search yammer data based on group name or tagID using yammer search rest api

Tags: rest, api, search, yammer

The Yammer REST documentation states that I need to query against this url: https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json

What I don't know is how to search for yammer data based on groups name or tags name. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with the correct syntax.

I know there is api to fetch the data from a single group. But I want to get the data from multiple groups or related to multiple tags.

Comment: Please enter a example of your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask